# Problem in oracle query

Tags: oracle

Hai guys,

I've a query in which i need to interchange the values of two fields.
The query is as follows:

```
SELECT TO_DATE(A.G_LEDGER_DATE,'dd/mm/YYY')as G_LEDGER_DATE,C.ACC_MASTER_NAME,
  A.G_LEDGER_REF_NO ,
  NVL(CASE WHEN B.G_LEDGER_SECTION = 1 THEN 
  CASE WHEN 
   (SELECT COUNT(*)FROM SOSTRANS.ACC_GEN_LEDGER WHERE G_LEDGER_SECTION = B.G_LEDGER_SECTION  AND G_LEDGER_ID = B.G_LEDGER_ID)> 1 THEN 
  B.G_LEDGER_VALUE  ELSE A.G_LEDGER_VALUE END END,0) AS G_LEDGER_DR_VALUE,  
  NVL(CASE WHEN B.G_LEDGER_SECTION = -1 THEN 
  CASE WHEN 
  (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM SOSTRANS.ACC_GEN_LEDGER WHERE G_LEDGER_SECTION = B.G_LEDGER_SECTION  AND G_LEDGER_ID = B.G_LEDGER_ID)> 1 THEN 
  B.G_LEDGER_VALUE ELSE A.G_LEDGER_VALUE END END,0) AS G_LEDGER_CR_VALUE,  
  B.G_LEDGER_SECTION,C.ACC_MASTER_ID,SUBSTR(A.G_LEDGER_REF_NO,0,3) AS Types,'Z' as OrderChar ,
    CASE WHEN A.G_LEDGER_REMARK IS NULL THEN B.G_LEDGER_REMARK ELSE A.G_LEDGER_REMARK END AS Narration 
    FROM SOSTRANS.ACC_GEN_LEDGER A  
    LEFT OUTER JOIN SOSTRANS.ACC_GEN_LEDGER B ON A.G_LEDGER_ID = B.G_LEDGER_ID  
    LEFT OUTER JOIN SOSMASTER.ACC_ACCOUNT_MASTER C ON A.ACC_MASTER_ID = C.ACC_MASTER_ID  WHERE A.G_LEDGER_CANCEL='N' AND
  B.ACC_MASTER_ID = 'MSOS000001' AND
  A.ACC_MASTER_ID <> 'MSOS000001' AND
  A.G_LEDGER_SECTION <> B.G_LEDGER_SECTION  AND
  A.G_LEDGER_DATE >= '25/sep/2009' AND
  A.G_LEDGER_DATE<='26/sep/2009' 
  ORDER BY OrderChar,G_LEDGER_DATE
```

Now i get the output as

```
...  G_LEDGER_DR_VALUE  G_LEDGER_CR_VALUE .....
...       2000                0           .....
...       3000                0           .....
...      -1000                0           .....
```

I need to get the negetive value of the G_LEDGER_DR_VALUE side in G_LEDGER_CR_VALUE and if negetive value exists in G_LEDGER_CR_VALUE then it should be in the G_LEDGER_DR_VALUE field
Can anyone help me to solve this?

Comment: I've been trying to understand what it is what you want but imho your question is not clear. What is a "-ve value"?

Comment: -ve means negetive value

Comment: This query is much too complicated (ie contains too many elements unrelated to your question). Can you simplify it so that we can see more clearly what your question lies exactly ?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question well, you select a value (that I will call `g_ledger_value`) that you want to appear in a different column depending on its sign.

This is how I would do it :

```
SELECT
    CASE WHEN t.g_ledger_value>0 THEN t.g_ledger_value ELSE 0 END AS g_ledger_dr_value,
    CASE WHEN t.g_ledger_value<0 THEN t.g_ledger_value ELSE 0 END AS g_ledger_cr_value
FROM
    (SELECT g_ledger_value FROM mytable) t;
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like a combination of SIGN() and CASE is what you need ...

```
CASE WHEN SIGN(G_LEDGER_DR_VALUE) = -1 then ...
ELSE ...
END
```

etc

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT G_LEDGER_DR_VALUE, 
       CASE WHEN G_LEDGER_DR_VALUE < 0 
        THEN G_LEDGER_CR_VALUE
        ELSE G_LEDGER_DR_VALUE
       END
FROM (...)
```

Is it that you mean? I suggest calculate values of CR___VALUE and DR_VALUE in subquery, and then in wrapping query make CASE which returns you correct value.